# "Speed of Convergence" for Different Probability Distributions

Tags: probability

I am interested in the following concept:

- The Law of Large Numbers tells us that the more we observe a random process, the closer the average of our observations becomes to the real average of the process.
- But is it possible that some random processes (i.e. probability distribution functions) require more observations to reach closer to their average compared to others?
- As a real world application, suppose we observe $n$ observations from a random variable $X$ having some unknown probability distribution $p(x; \theta)$. Suppose we believe that the underlying probability distribution responsible for generating this random data has a specific form $g(x; \theta)$ : is it possible to *a priori* know how many more random samples will be required to reliably (i.e. to a certain level of precision) estimate the mean of this distribution $g(x; \theta)$?
- More formally: For a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_n$, each with an expected value $E[X_i] = \mu$ and sample estimator $\overline{X_n}$ =  $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{{i=1}}^{n} x_i$ :

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} P\left( \left| \overline{X_n} - \mu \right| \geq \epsilon \right) = 0$$

Provided $X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_n$ are all iid and all come from some specific $g(x; \theta)$ , what value of $n$ is required to "probabilistically" achieve a certain value of $\epsilon$?

To explore this concept, here is a simulation experiment I did:

- For a Normal Distribution with a certain $\mu$ and $\sigma$, simulate 2 random points ad calculate the sample mean and variance. Repeat this for $n$ = 2,3,4,..100 points. Plot the results.
- Repeat this for a Poisson Distribution, Binomial Distribution, Exponential Distribution and Gamma Distribution.
- The goal is to see in which of these distributions do the sample means and sample variances approach the true means and true variances the fastest

Using the R programming language, we can see the results:

```
# parameters
mu <- 5
sigma <- 5
size <- 10
lambda <- 5
shape <- 5
rate <- 1
prob <- 0.5 

# Initialize 
sample_means <- matrix(nrow = 100, ncol = 5)
sample_vars <- matrix(nrow = 100, ncol = 5)

# generate samples and compute statistics
for (n in 2:100) {
    sample_means[n,] <- c(mean(rnorm(n, mean = mu, sd = sigma)), 
                          mean(rbinom(n, size = size, prob = prob)), 
                          mean(rpois(n, lambda = lambda)), 
                          mean(rgamma(n, shape = shape, rate = rate)), 
                          mean(rexp(n, rate = 1/mu)))
    
    sample_vars[n,] <- c(var(rnorm(n, mean = mu, sd = sigma)), 
                         var(rbinom(n, size = size, prob = prob)), 
                         var(rpois(n, lambda = lambda)), 
                         var(rgamma(n, shape = shape, rate = rate)), 
                         var(rexp(n, rate = 1/mu)))
}
```

[image]

In all of these simulations, the sample estimates approach the real estimates almost at the same "speed" as samples size increases.

**My Question:** Is it possible to identify a probability distribution function or a specific situation in which it is known to take much larger sample sizes on average for sample estimates to approach their true estimates? (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution)

Thanks!

Comment: But the distributions you simulated data for, the sample mean does not concentrate around the population mean at the same rate. I suggest that you change the scale of your plot, otherwise you will draw qualitatively false conclusions.

Comment: @Andrew: thank you so much for your reply! Can you please explain what you mean by "concentrate around the mean"? thank you so much!

Comment: one way to see it is to look at cramer's theorem

Comment: @Andrew: thank you so much for your reply! this is the first time I have heard about Cramer's theorem... I will take a look at it

Comment: just a question - how exactly can it be used to analyze my problem? would we construct rate functions for each of these pdf's?

Comment: cramer's theorem already says that the rate of convergence is different for, say the normal and poisson distribution. So I am not sure what else you are looking for

Comment: thank you so much for this clarification! if you have time, can you please recommend a link which shows how to calculate the convergence rate for given probability distribution? And re this comment "I suggest that you change the scale of your plot, otherwise you will draw qualitatively false conclusions." Given the convergence from Cramers Theorem, how do you suggest I change the plots I have made? Thank you so much for all your help today!